# grasping the meaning of the phrase

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning

In your opinion, is the following sentence (the first part of it) grammatically correct?

> "It boggled him Truman manned the Oval Office while they spent the
>   last of their meager savings on two hedonistic weeks of sun, surf and
>   sex".

Isn't there something amiss - say, a conjunction - between "it boggled him" and the Truman part? Or is the sentence all right as it is now?

And as for the meaning of the passage as well: does it imply that any reckless spending would've been considered paradoxical during Truman's presidency - on the grounds of times being economically tough? or some other reason?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It boggled him that.....a that is missing, of course. Looks like a copyediting error.

Comment: You most often hear _boggled_ applied to part of a person (specifically, to the person's mind) rather than to the person as a whole.

Comment: There's nothing inherently "ungrammatical" about deleting ***that*** in OP's cited context, even though almost certainly *most* writers would include it. I tracked down [the ebook source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rC-pBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&dq=%22Truman+manned+the+Oval+Office+while%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Truman%20manned%20the%20Oval%20Office%20while%22&f=false) - my guess is the "boggling" contrast is simply being drawn between doing "meaningful" things (like running a country) and mere self-indulgence. But mine and any other opinions are just that - POB.

Answer (score -1):

They writer tried to reduce the displaced apposition by eliding 'that'.  {Compare to: 'He told her [that] it was full.'}  Because the apposition is displaced from the dummy pronoun 'it', the listener is already straining and the omission of 'that' is too much.